# Monodevelop row selected on tableviewsource causes null reference exception

Tags: ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

```
public delegate bool SelectedValueForDropDown (string name);
public partial class BasicTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        SelectedValueForDropDown selValue;
        // Do something for the selected row
        string itemSel = this._tableItems[indexPath.Section];
        Console.WriteLine("90 the item selected is :{0}",itemSel);

        DetailViewController dvc = new DetailViewController();
        selValue = dvc.SelectedValueForPosition;
        //bool val = dvc.SelectedValueForPosition(itemSel);
        ValueSelectedDD valDD = new ValueSelectedDD();

        bool success = valDD.HandleValueSelected(selValue);
        Console.WriteLine("100 the value is : {0}",success);
    }
.....
} //class closed

public class ValueSelectedDD
{
    public bool HandleValueSelected (SelectedValueForDropDown selValue)
    {
        bool success =false;
        success = selValue("CEO");

        return success;
    }
}
//This method is in DetailViewController.designer.cs class.
public bool SelectedValueForPosition (string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the value selected is :{0}",name);
        btnPosition.SetTitle(name,UIControlState.Normal); //Exception occurs here
        return true;
    }
```

I am working on simple MonoDevelop projects.So i have a tableview as pop up for my button. I click it and i have 3 options. I choose one and the button should get its label replaced by option selected. The row selected is in a tableviewsource class. DetailViewController is the class where i have the actual button to be clicked. I am getting an exception of

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

 at EmployeeWithDropDown.DetailViewController.SelectedValueForPosition (System.String name) [0x0000b] in /Users/.../EmployeeWithDropDown/EmployeeWithDropDown/DetailViewController.designer.cs:106

 at EmployeeWithDropDown.ValueSelectedDD.HandleValueSelected (EmployeeWithDropDown.SelectedValueForDropDown selValue) [0x00002] in /Users/.../EmployeeWithDropDown/EmployeeWithDropDown/BasicTableViewSource.cs:109
   at EmployeeWithDropDown.BasicTableViewSource.RowSelected (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00036] in /Users/.../EmployeeWithDropDown/EmployeeWithDropDown/BasicTableViewSource.cs:99

 at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at EmployeeWithDropDown.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/.../EmployeeWithDropDown/EmployeeWithDropDown/Main.cs:17

System.NullReferenceException has been thrown.
Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

if you need more info, please ask. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
public partial class PopoverContentViewcontroller : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        table = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
        table.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        string[] tableItems = new string[]{"CEO","Developer","IT"};
        //List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words); 
        List<string> lst = new List<string>(tableItems);

        table.Source = new BasicTableViewSource(lst);
        Add (table);
       }
 .....
}
```

This is the popovercontroller that populates the table for drop down. i.e. the values here get populated in the drop down ..

EDIT2:

```
                    DetailViewController dvc;
                    .....
            table.Source = new BasicTableViewSource(lst,dvc);
        Add (table);
```

Comment: This is very confusing.  Is DetailViewController the parent or the child of the tableview (who calls whom?).  In RowSelected you() create a new instance of DVC, but don't display it.  If btnPosition is a UI element on DVC, it probably does not exist (ie, it's NULL) if the DVC has not been rendered yet.

Comment: @Jason. I added some code. So i have btnPosition on DetailViewController. Clicking that populates a uitableviewcontroller from Popoverviewcontentcontroller. Then a row is selected. The row selected in basictableviewsource gets called. I get the value "CEO" for example. Then my intention is to launch a delegate from Rowselected to DetailViewController class and then get the selected value as label on the button. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of DetailViewController in your RowSelected method.  What you need is a reference to the DetailViewController that already exists.

When you create your TableViewController, you need to pass in a reference to the "parent" DetailViewController.  That way in your RowSelected method you can call a method on the already existing DVC.

Comment: I made a new change by name EDIT2 in my code. I passed reference of DetailViewController to my BasicTableViewSource, but still its showing exception. I used that reference in RowSelected and i got this exception : NSInvalidArgumentException Reason : - [DetailViewController btnPositionClick:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance. Can you explain it more or point out where i am going wrong.

Comment: I don't think I can answer this without seeing more of your code.  I'd suggest moving this to the Xamarin forums, which is better suited to an extended discussion.

Comment: I did that yesterday itself. But no reply from there as well.

Comment: The question you posted was basically just a link to SO.  I'd suggest you post the complete source for the two controllers you're dealing with, so we can see the context of what you're doing.

Comment: I posted the link for the complete project there. Can you check it out?

Comment: I got it. I did something like this var content = new PopoverController (this); When i started my popovercontroller from parent dvc and used/passed the reference throughout the program where i needed it and i got it.